# What is the reasoning behind defining event handlers for every possible event, even when they're not used?

Tags: c#, winforms

I came upon some code in an application I'm supposed to update that defines an event handler for **every** possible event of a control (or at least all of the ones listed in the designer, from what I can tell). I've never seen this before and have no desire to implement it in any of my applications.

One example; a button that starts a logging operation begins the operation on `Click`. However, *all other event handlers are also bound*, from `AutoSizeChanged` and `BackColorChanged` right down to `VisibleChanged` and `Validating`. With the exception of `Click`, all event handlers are empty. From what I can tell so far, this happens with many controls throughout the application.

No comments are provided detailing why this is the case either. Why would this be done?

Comment: Someone might have added some empty event handlers so that they would have a place to set breakpoints during development, then failed to houseclean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the exception of Click, all event handlers are empty. From what I can tell so far, this happens with many controls throughout the application.
>
> Why would this be done?

Most likely because the original author didn't understand that it was not necessary.

There is no good technical reason to do this.  It actually just decreases performance, and provides no benefit.

Note that many people, when they create an event on their own class, often subscribe an empty event handler.  This makes it so they can avoid the null check on the subscription list.  I suspect this was done as a misguided attempt to prevent that, even though it's typically done on the event publishing side, not the subscription side of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

That is.... not the ideal case. In fact, most winforms controls use `EventHandlerList`, which is designed to be an efficient storage model for **sparse** events. If you are overriding events for the thing you are subclassing (the form etc), then `override` is a preferred option to event subscriptions.

It sounds like somebody has gone through double clicking events in the IDE to make them all bold. It serves no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally remove empty event handlers. This is probably a developer that is "thinking about the future" and wants have some code ready "if we need it".

I note that:

- The event handlers are easily created when needed.
- Empty event handlers are *unused code* and makes the important part hard to *find* and *read*.

I would thus adhere to the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle and promptly remove them.

Comment: I planned to remove them and am in the process of doing so. This is a fairly simple application, so I'm almost certain that virtually all of these event handlers won't be used any time in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 1):

With older versions of Visual Studio, once you inserted a new event handler it did not automatically delete the code from the designer.cs file when you deleted the event handler method. You had to go into the Windows Form Designer generated code and find/delete the line like:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

or else you'd get build errors if you deleted the button1_Click method. It was a pain and that might be why he never cleaned them up. Now it's smart enough to delete the wire up when you delete the event handler method.

Comment: This code wasn't in the `designer.cs` file, though. I'm not referring to the code to bind the event handler (the code you included in your answer); I'm referring to the actual method declarations in the main `.cs` file.

Comment: It's just lazy coding for empty and unused methods to be in production code. If it was an API and there were some deprecated methods, you might leave the method signatures there with a deprecated attribute that points developers to the new implementation.